# Remove particular query string parameter value from url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an url like this 
http://localhost/hotelbooking/hotels.php?city=berlin&start=Feb+17%2C+Fri&end=Feb+24%2C+Fri&room=1&guest=1&search_hotel=&roomfacility=1,2,3 and I want to remove one number from parameter value of roomfacility.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you want to get the querystring in a variable, without that value or do you want to redirect to the same url but without that value?  What are you hoping to achieve by doing this?

Comment: @Shine php is not in the question tags.

Comment: Use window.location.href that returns a string of your url and then manipulate the string with substr() function

Comment: @Archer yes i want to redirect to the same url but without that value.

Comment: You should fix whatever sends you to that page in the first place, rather than try and fix an issue when you get there.  You're likely to end up in a redirect loop with your suggested fix.

Comment: This is for remove duplicate numbers in url like (&roomfacility=1,2,3,3,3)

Comment: Okay.  Why are they there?  Something is redirecting you to that Url, and *that is where the problem is*.

Comment: You should filter value before sending url. Where are you getting these values?

Comment: @MayaShah from checkbox I am getting that values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use selected checkbox values to use in url use this.

```
var facilities = $.map($("input:checkbox[name=YourInputName]:checked"), function(n, i){ return n.value; }).join(',');
```